# Using a player's stats in multiple different classes

Tags: java, oop, methods

I'm making a text adventure RPG game, where you can enter a battle, and follow a semi open world story. I made a player class, which I use to hold all of the player's stats.

```
public class Player {

    // Generic Stats
    int playerLevel = 1;
    int playerHealth = 20;
    int EXP = 0;
    long money = 0;
    String name = "";
    String homeland = "";

    // Skills
    int fighting = 5;
    int block = 5;
    int doctor = 5;
    int speech = 5;

    // Attributes
    int damage = fighting * 2;

    // Prints the player's stats
    public void printStats() {          
        System.out.println();
        System.out.println("Level: " + playerLevel);
        System.out.println("EXP: " + EXP);
        System.out.println("HP: " + playerHealth);
        System.out.println("Money: " + money);
        System.out.println("Name: " + name);
        System.out.println("Homeland: " + homeland );
        System.out.println("Skills: Fighting: " + fighting + " Block: " + block + "Doctor: " + doctor + " Speech: " + speech);
        System.out.println();
    }

    // Changes the player's level
    public void changeLevel(int newLevel) {         
        playerLevel = newLevel;
    }

    // Levels up the player
    public void levelUp() {
        playerLevel++;
        EXP = 0;
    }

    // Give the player health
    public void addHealth(int addedHealth) {
        playerHealth = playerHealth + addedHealth;
    }

    // Remove the player's health
    public void removeHealth(int removedHealth) {
        playerHealth = playerHealth - removedHealth;
    }

    // Give the player money
    public void giveMoney(int givenMoney) {
        money = money + givenMoney;
    }

    // Give the player EXP
    public void giveEXP(int addedEXP) {
        EXP = EXP + addedEXP;
    }

    // Change the player's homeland
    public void changeHomeland(String newHomeland) {
        homeland = newHomeland;
    }

    // Change the player's name
    public void changeName(String newName) {
        name = newName;
    }

    // Increase Fighting
    public void increaseFightingSkill(int amountAdded) {
        fighting = fighting + amountAdded;
    }

    // Decrease Fighting
    public void decreaseFightingSkill(int amountdecreased) {
        fighting = fighting - amountdecreased;
    }

    // Increase Block
    public void increaseBlockSkill(int amountAdded) {
        block = block + amountAdded;
    }

    // Decrease Block
    public void decreaseBlockSkill(int amountdecreased) {
        block = block - amountdecreased;
    }

    // Increase Doctor
    public void increaseDoctorSkill(int amountAdded) {
        doctor = doctor + amountAdded;          
    }

    // Decrease Doctor
    public void decreaseDoctorSkill(int amountdecreased) {
        doctor = doctor - amountdecreased;
    }

    // Increase Speech
    public void increaseSpeechSkill(int amountAdded) {
        speech = speech + amountAdded;
    }

    // Decrease Speech
    public void decreaseSpeechSkill(int amountdecreased) {
        speech = speech - amountdecreased;
    }

}
```

As you can see, you can also alter the player's stats here. I'm making a main class, where I simply initialize the player, and modify their stats as the player makes decisions, wins battles, etc. I initialize the player here in the main class.

```
Player player = new Player();
```

Now that it is initialized, I made a "Battle" class. The concept is that I want to simply initialize the battle, and modify the contents of the battle and be done with it (like a battle template I can drop in the code). Sorta like this :

```
battle.enemySetHealth() // example modifier
battle.start() // simply run through the battle
```

The problem is, I want to use the player stats in the battle class, without actually just defining another player, I want to use the same player object, because I will be modifying the player's stats in the main class, and if I define a new one, it will have different stats in the battle class, messing up the entire thing. I will use the player stats in the battle class to determine attack damage, chance to block incoming attacks, e.t.c. here is the battle class:

```
import java.util.Random;
import java.util.Scanner;

// Battle Scene
public class Battle {
    //Variables
    String enemyName = "Unnamed Enemy";
    int enemyHealth = 20;
    int enemyAttack = 5;
    int enemyDefense = 5;
    int enemyDisposition = 0;
    int attackDamage;
    // Sets up tools
    clear clear = new clear();
    Scanner sc = new Scanner(System.in);
    Random rand = new Random();

    // Allows changing of enemy name
    public void enemyName(String newEnemyName) {
        enemyName = newEnemyName;
    }

    // Sets a new disposition for the enemy to start the fight with
    public void enemyStartingDisposition(int newStartingDisposition) {
        enemyDisposition = newStartingDisposition;
    }

    // Sets a new amount of health for the enemy to start with
    public void enemyStartingHealth(int newStartingHealth) {
        enemyHealth = newStartingHealth;
    }

    // Sets a new defense for the enemy to start with
    public void enemyStartingDefense(int newEnemyDefense) {
        enemyDefense = newEnemyDefense;
    }

    // Sets a new attack for the enemy to start with
    public void enemyStartingAttack(int newEnemyAttack) {
        enemyAttack = newEnemyAttack;
    }

    // Starts the battle
    public void startFight() throws InterruptedException {
        System.out.println("Woah! " + enemyName + " jumped out of nowhere!!!");
        System.out.println("(Attack)");
        System.out.println("(Talk)");
        System.out.println("(Run)");
        while (true) {
            System.out.print("What should you do? : ");
            String userInput = sc.nextLine();
            if (userInput.equals("Attack")) {
                // hopefully put in a way to attack based on your stats
            } if (userInput.equals("Talk")) {
                // a way to use speech to talk your way out of the fight
            } if (userInput.equals("Run")) {
                //ability to run away based on agility/speed 
            } else {
                System.out.println();
                System.out.println("Invalid Answer!");
                Thread.sleep(2000);
                clear.Screen();
            }   
        }
        //Break here
    }
}
```

I also want to modify the player's stats at the end, like money and exp earned. So how can I do this? It is getting really confusing.

Comment: Please re-format your code to improve readability. Why is this important? Well it doesn't matter if you're the only one reading and studying the code, but that's changed once you've posted it on a site that is staffed by volunteers, since now it is in **your** interest to help make it as easy to understand and read your code as possible. All nested blocks should be indented 4 spaces. All code on the same block should have the same indentation. There never should be more than one blank line in a row.... Your help in  this would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: A `Battle` should take either 2 players as references or a player and an enemy depending on your goal, and whether the enemy would differ from a normal player.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can pass the Player entity as an actual parameter to the method of the Battle class and return the current entity as a parameter.
Sample code as below:

Battle class code:

```
public class Battle {
    //battle win function
    public Player winBattle(Player player){
        /**
         * win rules
         */
        player.setStatus("dead");
        return player;
    }

}
```

Player class code:

```
Player player = new Player();
Battle battle=new Battle();
player=battle.run(player);
```

Comment: So I essentially run the battle through the player?

Comment: Why do you need to return the player?

Comment: @CuriousMan You can  initialize both of the two entities in your business logic or in a main method~

Answer (score 0):

What your going to want do do is pass the player object you create in the main class to your startfight() method in the battle class. Then, in the startfight you will be able to access all of the player's stats without having to redefine them. It also might be useful to create an Enemy class to represent an ememy in your game. That way you wont need to have the stats for an enemy defined in the battle class. Also, because the Player and Enemy share some stats (like damage and name), it might be useful to create a [superclass](http://journals.ecs.soton.ac.uk/java/tutorial/java/javaOO/subclasses.html) that has damage and name as instance variables to avoid code duplication. Because the player playing is always the same, we can have the player as an instance varible for battle (because you only want to use one instance of the battle class)With all that said, here is your code incorporating my proposed changes.

GameUnit.java

```
/**
 * Represents a game unit - a Player or an Enemy because they both share common stats
 */
public class GameUnit {
    int attackDamage;// your "damage" in the player class and "enemyAttack" in the battle class
    int health = 5;// "playerHealth" in the player class and "enemyHealth" in the battle class
    int defense = 5;

    String name = "unnamed game unit";

    public void printStats() {
        System.out.println();
        System.out.println("Game Unit attackDamage: " + attackDamage);
        System.out.println("Game Unit health: " + health);
        System.out.println("GameUnit defense: " + defense);
    }

    // Give the unit health
    public void addHealth(int addedHealth) {
        health = health + addedHealth;
    }

    public void setHealth(int newHealth) {
        health = newHealth;
    }

    // Remove the player's health
    public void removeHealth(int removedHealth) {
        health = health - removedHealth;
    }

    // Change the unit's name
    public void changeName(String newName) {
        name = newName;
    }

    public void setAttackDamage(int attackDamage) {
        this.attackDamage = attackDamage;
    }

    // Increase Block
    public void increaseBlockSkill(int amountAdded) {
        defense = defense + amountAdded;
    }

    // Decrease Block
    public void decreaseBlockSkill(int amountdecreased) {
        defense = defense - amountdecreased;
    }

    public void setDefense(int defense) {
        this.defense = defense;
    }
}
```

Player.java

```
public class Player extends GameUnit {
    int level = 1;
    // health is now in GameUnit because enemy needs health too
    int EXP = 0;
    long money = 0;
    String homeland = "";

    int fighting = 5;
    //block is defense in GameUnit
    int doctor = 5;
    int speech = 5;

    // Constructor that sets name from "unnamed game unit" to Player
    public Player() {
        name = "Player";// Set the name declared in the GameUnit class to player because this instance is the player
        attackDamage = fighting * 2;
    }

    // Override printStats in GameUnit to print the remaining player stats
    public void printStats() {
        super.printStats();// Prints attack damage and health
        System.out.println("Player level: " + level);
        System.out.println("Health: " + health);
        System.out.println("EXP: " + EXP);
        System.out.println("money " + money);
        System.out.println("Homeland: " + homeland);
        System.out.println("Skills: Fighting: " + fighting + "Doctor: " + doctor + " Speech: " + speech);
        System.out.println();
    }


    // Changes the player's level
    public void changeLevel(int newLevel) {

        level = newLevel;
    }

    // Levels up the player
    public void levelUp() {
        level++;
        EXP = 0;
    }// Give the player money
    public void giveMoney(int givenMoney) {
        money = money + givenMoney;
    }

    // Give the player EXP
    public void giveEXP(int addedEXP) {
        EXP = EXP + addedEXP;
    }

    // Change the player's homeland
    public void changeHomeland(String newHomeland) {
        homeland = newHomeland;
    }

    // Increase Fighting
    public void increaseFightingSkill(int amountAdded) {
        fighting = fighting + amountAdded;
    }

    // Decrease Fighting
    public void decreaseFightingSkill(int amountdecreased) {
        fighting = fighting - amountdecreased;
    }

    // Increase Doctor
    public void increaseDoctorSkill(int amountAdded) {
        doctor = doctor + amountAdded;

    }

    // Decrease Doctor
    public void decreaseDoctorSkill(int amountdecreased) {
        doctor = doctor - amountdecreased;
    }

    // Increase Speech
    public void increaseSpeechSkill(int amountAdded) {
        speech = speech + amountAdded;
    }

    // Decrease Speech
    public void decreaseSpeechSkill(int amountdecreased) {
        speech = speech - amountdecreased;
    }
}
```

Enemy.java

```
public class Enemy extends GameUnit {
    //enemyHealth is health in GameUnit
    //enemyAttack is attackDamage in GameUnit
    int enemyDisposition = 0;

    //No need for setEnemy name because changeName does the perfect thing in GameUnit

    //Set health does the job of enemyStartingHealth
    public void setEnemyDisposition(int enemyDisposition) {
        this.enemyDisposition = enemyDisposition;
    }

}
```

Battle.java

```
import java.util.*;

public class Battle {
    private Player player;
    private Enemy enemy;

    private Clear clear = new Clear();// Remember Java classes are supposed to start with upper cases
    private Scanner sc = new Scanner(System.in);
    private Random rand = new Random();

    public Battle(Player thePlayer) {// Pass our only instance of player
        player = thePlayer;// Because objects are passed by reference in Java,
        // player will be the same instance of Player. In other words, when
        // you modify the player object in main, the instance variables in this
        // player reference will change accordingly because player in this class
        // and player in main both point to the same object
    }

    public void setEnemy(Enemy newEnemy) {
        enemy = newEnemy;
    }

    // Starts the battle
    public void startFight() {

        System.out.println("Woah! " + enemy.name + " jumped out of nowhere!!!");
        System.out.println("(Attack)");
        System.out.println("(Talk)");
        System.out.println("(Run)");
        boolean won = false;
        while (true) {

            if (enemy.health <= 0) {// enemy is dead
                won = true;
                break;
            }

            if (player.health <= 0) {// player is dead
                won = false;
                break;
            }

            System.out.print("What should you do? : ");
            String userInput = sc.nextLine();
            if (userInput.equals("Attack")) {
                enemy.removeHealth(player.attackDamage);// hurt the enemy or whatever
                // hopefully put in a way to attack based on your stats
            }
            if (userInput.equals("Talk")) {
                if (player.speech > 10) {
                    // ...
                }

            }
            if (userInput.equals("Run")) {
                // ability to run away based on agility/speed

            } else {
                System.out.println();
                System.out.println("Invalid Answer!");
                try {
                    Thread.sleep(2000);
                } catch (Exception e) {
                    // ignore all exceptions
                }
                clear.screen();// and methods are supposed to use lower camel case so the first word (screen) is lowercase
            }
        }
        if (won) {
            player.money += 1000;
            player.giveEXP(10);
            if (player.EXP > 100) {
                player.levelUp();
            }
        } else {
            player.money -= 500;
        }
        // Break here

    }

}
```

Main.java

```
public class Main {

    public static void main(String[] args) {

        Player player = new Player();

        Battle battle = new Battle(player);// Pass player to battle

        Enemy firstEnemy = new Enemy();
        firstEnemy.changeName("First Enemy");

        battle.setEnemy(firstEnemy);
        battle.startFight();
        // ...do other battles, create new enemies with random stats etc...
    }
}
```

The Java library uses a hierarchy too: [link](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/lang/package-tree.html)

If this hierarchy business doesn't make sense, it might be beneficial to improve your Java skills a little before continuing your game. Once you fell confident, my setup might not encapsulate how you want to represent your game objects (player and enemies) so you might want to draw out a [UML diagram](http://www.cs.bsu.edu/~pvg/misc/uml/) showing what a player and an enemy have in common (health, block), however a player might have some things that a enemy may now (level, xp etc.). With this knowledge, you can reconstruct a hierarchy so you don't have to worry about how everything is stored and you can work uninterrupted on content.

Good inheritance / hierarchy example [here](http://www.informit.com/articles/article.aspx?p=1021579)

Answer (score 0):

The accepted answer is fine enough, but I think it's worth noting that if you are only having one player in the entire game, you should create a `public static Player` in your main class, as so:

```
public class Main {

public static Player player;

public static void main(String args[]) {
player = new Player();
//...
battle.start();
}

}
```

And then in the Battle class, when you want to reward the player exp (or something else) you can simply:

```
Main.player.rewardExp(25);
```

or

```
Main.player.exp += 25;
```

I personally feel for your game this makes more technical sense, but if you were to add more players or enemies, it would make more sense to approach it like this:

```
Battle b = new Battle(player, enemy);
battle.start();
```

Passing the parameters of a Player and an Enemy and then storing them as variable for each instance of a battle allows the Battle to access them easily.

**EDIT: ** you may also want to consider making an Entity class.
Certain variables (traits, stats) of your player such as HP, power, whatever, are also stats that enemies have.

In order to prevent writing the same code twice, you can make a --SUPERCLASS-- that has variables such as `HP` and `POWER` and `EXP`.

Then just have your Player class and Enemy class `extends Entity` and you can use those stats for both without writing them in both classes. 
You can even have preset methods such as `die()`, `giveExp()`, `loseHp()`.

Hope I explained that well enough.